# Using base Amazon linux AMI seems to use GPU AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-linux

I having been setting up our prod infrastructure and have noticed that when using the ami-1c47407f ap-southeast-2 image, it seems to be using this within the ec2 instances themselves - `amzn-ami-hvm-2016.09.1.20170119-x86_64-gp2 (ami-1c47407f)`. Just curious why it's actually using the `gp2` part which from what I understand is used for NVIDIA/GPU instances which we are not using (we are on a t2.small). Does this mean we will be getting charged for the image? or will we only be charged if we use it with a GPU instance type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gp2 probably refers to the [GP2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html) "general purpose solid state disk", though the AMI can be run with any disk type. I think you're referring to the [G2 instance type](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-g2-instance-type-with-4x-more-gpu-power/).

As EEAA says, you pay for the instance type you're running.

Answer (score 1):

You will only be charged for the instance type you're running.